# Is there a command to get the number of frames in a gif?

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, image-processing, gif

Is there a command to get the number of frames in a gif?
I have some gifs, and I want to convert them into arrays, but I want to limit the array, and structure of the array based on the number of frames in any random gif I happen to feed my program. I was thinking imagemagick might have such an option, but i haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you have ImageMagick installed, you can use its `identify` command as follows

```
identify /path/to/image.gif
```

You'll get details of each frame.

As suggested by [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver), you can get the number of images in the sequence directly using the `%n` output format specifier, however rather annoyingly it appears to print it once for each image. To get a single number you could do

```
identify -format "%n\n" path/to/file.gif | head -1
```

Comment: Oopsie. I was the first to post an answer and then updated it 3 times without seeing your answer which is quite similar to my last revision...

Answer (score 22):

**Exiftool** will list the **Frame Count** as part of its extensive output.

This a command and output of an Animated Gif file:

```
$ exiftool -b -FrameCount giphy.gif
33
```

**Full exiftool output on the gif:**

```
$ exiftool giphy.gif
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.10
File Name                       : giphy.gif
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 2.1 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2018:04:22 21:00:42-04:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2018:04:22 21:01:03-04:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2018:04:22 21:00:52-04:00
File Permissions                : rw-rw-r--
File Type                       : GIF
File Type Extension             : gif
MIME Type                       : image/gif
GIF Version                     : 89a
Image Width                     : 500
Image Height                    : 281
Has Color Map                   : Yes
Color Resolution Depth          : 7
Bits Per Pixel                  : 7
Background Color                : 127
Animation Iterations            : Infinite
XMP Toolkit                     : Adobe XMP Core 5.3-c011 66.145661, 2012/02/06-14:56:27
Creator Tool                    : Adobe Photoshop CS6 (Macintosh)
Instance ID                     : xmp.iid:C312DB1DA6A311E5B8F5D2BA262E999D
Document ID                     : xmp.did:C312DB1EA6A311E5B8F5D2BA262E999D
Derived From Instance ID        : xmp.iid:C312DB1BA6A311E5B8F5D2BA262E999D
Derived From Document ID        : xmp.did:C312DB1CA6A311E5B8F5D2BA262E999D
Frame Count                     : 33
Duration                        : 2.31 s
Image Size                      : 500x281
Megapixels                      : 0.141
```

Comment: You don't need to `grep` `exiftool`'s output: every field can be printed independently: `exiftool dev/slack-emojinator/gifs/yj_batsu.gif -FrameCount` and `exiftool dev/slack-emojinator/gifs/yj_batsu.gif -b -FrameCount` for just the value

Comment: @muru Thanks for the information.  I'll fix the answer.

Comment: Here's some useful information:  On Ubuntu (21.10), the `exiftool` program is found on the [`libimage-exiftool-perl`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/libimage-exiftool-perl) package and can be installed with `apt install libimage-exiftool-perl`.  On Arch Linux (2021), it is found on the [`perl-image-exiftool`](https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/perl-image-exiftool/) package.

Answer (score 10):

#### One-liner command

Inspired by this [article](https://gnutips.wordpress.com/2010/08/10/view-image-file-metadata-from-the-command-line/), use this one-liner command:

```
$ identify drop_caches.gif | wc -l
128
```

For more details use:

```
identify -verbose filename.gif
```

---

This [website](https://ezgif.com/split/ezgif-3-a91fe0e517.gif) lets you upload your `.gif` and analyzes it many ways including the number of frames in it:

[image: ezgif.png]

---

The `convert` provided by **Image Magic** will convert your `.gif` into individual `.png` images one for each frame:

```
$ convert -verbose -coalesce drop_caches.gif drop_caches.png
drop_caches.gif[0] GIF 470x940 470x940+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 177KB 0.090u 0:00.099
drop_caches.gif[1] GIF 13x1 470x940+398+704 8-bit sRGB 256c 177KB 0.080u 0:00.089
drop_caches.gif[2] GIF 306x620 470x940+144+130 8-bit sRGB 256c 177KB 0.080u 0:00.089
    (... SNIP ...)
drop_caches.gif=>drop_caches-125.png[125] GIF 470x940 470x940+0+0 8-bit sRGB 255c 50.3KB 27.100u 0:24.890
drop_caches.gif=>drop_caches-126.png[126] GIF 470x940 470x940+0+0 8-bit sRGB 254c 48.9KB 27.320u 0:25.089
drop_caches.gif=>drop_caches-127.png[127] GIF 470x940 470x940+0+0 8-bit sRGB 254c 48.9KB 27.480u 0:25.269
```

Answer (score 7):

FFmpeg way:

```
ffprobe -v warning -show_frames qqq.gif | grep -c '\[/FRAME\]'
```

Gif video is a video, so video analysis tools may also help.

Comment: My experience is that compiling FFMPEG to meet my needs is a bitch, but I do appreciate the time it took to make this answer.I hope someone finds it useful

Comment: @j0h, Doesn't distro-provided FFmpeg just work for this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `less` command too if you have `ImageMagick` installed.

```
less +G image.gif
```

Total frames is the last `#` in brackets in  `image.gif[#]...` (starting from 0); Or count with:

```
less image.gif | wc -l
```

Comment: intriguing.......